# ASP.NET MVC and HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I deployed my ASP.NET MVC application to my local IIS (same computer) and I'm getting

```
HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized
```

after accessing the application through the browser.

I'm using forms authetication and on the development server it works fine.

I depolyed also a default ASP.NET MVC project and its working fine, so it must be something application related. Is there any way to get more information on this particular error ? Any log file or something. The message HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized isn't realy helpful.

Tested on
Windows 7,IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5

**EDIT**

Found some logs c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\ but there wasn't anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set permissions on the folder.

Try granting permissions to the IIS APPPOOL\YourPoolUserNameHere
or to the IIS_IUSRS user group if the first one doesn't do the trick.

Comment: This is not working and the default ASP.NET MVC application is working fine without any permision granting.